# Replacing UINavigationController With A UIViewController in MainWindows.xib

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, replace, homescreen

I am a newbie to iPhone app development. I want to make a simple app using *view-based template* which will have a **main menu (home screen)** linking to different modules of the app. Modules will themselves be made up of either `UINavigationController` or `UITabController`.

First I just wanted to create and bug a module, so I took a NavigationController in `MainWndows.xib(appDelegate)` and `stacked(linked)` many `ViewControllers` to it.

Now I need to have main menu at **start of app**, where I have placed `NavigationController`. I am now confused what to do? I have got solution in my mind that place this `NavigationController` in new xib file and a `mainMenuViewController` in **MainWindow.xib** file and access navigation module as a modal. So my Question is that if my approach is right? How will I access this modal controller to push viewcontrollers onto it? Or is there other alternate for what I want..?

I hope my Question is clear...
Any suggestion or link is appreciable.

Comment: better design it using a storyboard when you deal with multiple view controllers

Comment: Could you please post your AppDelegate code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got a better idea in my mind. I am going to stick with NavigationController in MainWindows.xib. I will push Main Menu as Root view Controller with both its *navigation bar* and *toolbar* hidden. Depending upon the button tapped, I will further push appropriate View Controllers on NavigationController.